# Get top rows from column value count with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have this kind of data. It's a set of reviews of some products.

```
prod_id text    rating
AB123   some text   5
AB123   some text   2
AB123   some text   4
AC456   some text   3
AC456   some text   2
AD777   some text   2
AD777   some text   5
AD777   some text   5
AD777   some text   4
AE999   some text   4
AF000   some text   5
AG222   some text   5
AG222   some text   3
AG222   some text   3
```

I want to know which product has the most reviews (the most rows), so I use the following code to get the top 3 products (I only need 3 top most reviewed products).

```
s = df['prod_id'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).head(3)
```

And then I will get this result.

```
AD777   4
AB123   3
AG222   3
```

But what I actually need is the rows with the ids as above. I need the whole rows of all AD777, AB123, and AG222, like below.

```
product_id  text    rating
AD777   some text   2
AD777   some text   5
AD777   some text   5
AD777   some text   4
AB123   some text   5
AB123   some text   2
AB123   some text   4
AG222   some text   5
AG222   some text   3
AG222   some text   3
```

How do I do that? I tried the `print(df.iloc[s])`, but of course it's not working. As I read on the documentation, `value_counts` return series and not dataframe. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `left` join with `DataFrame` created with `index` of `s`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'prod_id':s.index}).merge(df, how='left')
print (df)
  prod_id       text  rating
0   AD777  some text       2
1   AD777  some text       5
2   AD777  some text       5
3   AD777  some text       4
4   AB123  some text       5
5   AB123  some text       2
6   AB123  some text       4
7   AG222  some text       5
8   AG222  some text       3
9   AG222  some text       3
```

Comment: This looks very elegant !

Comment: Wow, I must say this works really great. And it's pretty fast too, I apply it on my ~1.6 GB of dataset and it runs around 30 second. Thank you very much! Plus, I must say that @MaxU and Wen solutions are actually great too (and also as fast), but I have to choose yours for efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

Try this ?

```
df[df.prod_id.isin(df.prod_id.value_counts().head(3).index)]
```

EDIT:
Thanks for @jezrael point out the order problem.

```
df.assign(Forsort=df.prod_id.map(df.prod_id.value_counts().head(3))).\
      dropna().sort_values('Forsort',ascending=False).drop('Forsort',axis=1)



Out[150]: 
   prod_id  text  rating
5    AD777  some       2
6    AD777  some       5
7    AD777  some       5
8    AD777  some       4
0    AB123  some       5
1    AB123  some       2
2    AB123  some       4
11   AG222  some       5
12   AG222  some       3
13   AG222  some       3
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one-liner solution which doesn't use a helper series:

```
In [63]: df.assign(rank=df.groupby('prod_id')['prod_id']
    ...:                  .transform('size')
    ...:                  .rank(method='dense', ascending=False)) \
    ...:   .sort_values('rank') \
    ...:   .query("rank <= 3") \
    ...:   .drop('rank', 1)
Out[63]:
   prod_id       text  rating
5    AD777  some text       2
6    AD777  some text       5
7    AD777  some text       5
8    AD777  some text       4
0    AB123  some text       5
1    AB123  some text       2
2    AB123  some text       4
11   AG222  some text       5
12   AG222  some text       3
13   AG222  some text       3
3    AC456  some text       3
4    AC456  some text       2
```

But if you already have your `s` series, then @jezrael's solution looks much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

This was the easiest solution that worked for me:

```
Df.groupby('prod_id').first()
```